# Google search via Tor browser

Tags: google

Firstly I'm not very technical. I use Tor browser because zScaler blocks IE and Chrome and I don't know any other way around it. Google access wasn't too bad until I upgraded to the latest Tor browser. Now every Google search returns the message:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. Please try your request again later. Why did this happen?

I have read about why this happens, but I am wondering if there is a way around this. I tried the New Identity feature to no avail.

Look forward to your answers

Comment: Long story short: No, not with Tor.

Comment: Don't use GOOGLE at all... They track your every move online.
Use [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) or [StartPage](https://www.startpage.com/).
Those Search Engines ***DON'T*** track you.

Comment: Use searx.me or searx.at. It's better than standard Google.

Comment: You can use google through a proxy web site like https://whoer.net/webproxy. This way tor does not get banned.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "High" Security Setting in the TorButton, go to https://ipv4.google.com, enter you search engine, and you will get a much simpler captcha (only text), and your search query will most likely work. (from my experience)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Google, you can use DuckDuckGo which has a Tor hidden service so no exit nodes are used: **3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion**